# PS command returns different format in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash

This is the content of `a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(ps ax |wc -l)
```

This is what I see on my shell:

```
$ ps ax |wc -l
109
$ ./a.sh
111
```

Obviously those 2 numbers should be the same. The difference seems the way `ps` formats the results is different in the bash script, but I can't figure out why? This is on a CentOS 7 system.

**EDIT:**

This isn't just a matter of additional shell processes being spawned as some comments make it sound. Take this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(ps -ax |grep httpd)"
```

The output:

```
$ ./a.sh
10052 ?        S      0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
10230 ?        Ss     0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13790 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13839 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13848 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13852 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
16015 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18805 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18865 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18866 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18886 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

$ ps ax|grep httpd
10052 ?        S      0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
10230 ?        Ss     0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13790 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13839 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13848 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
13852 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
16015 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18805 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18865 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18866 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
18886 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
20565 pts/0    R+     0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

So here the shell script returns *less* lines than the bash prompt command does.

Comment: Why do you think they should be equal? Did you find somewhere in SO referencing such a fact? They obviously won't be the same! `$(..)` runs a sub-shell from the parent shell in which the script is run.

Comment: Huh -- I'm trying to figure out what to do with this question. Is this the thinko equivalent of "close-as-typo"?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think you should explain what is happening here. Who else if not you? ;)

Comment: @Inian You're actually right about the sub-shell, that was the issue. I still don't understand why that's the case tho. If you run `ps |grep` from a bash prompt, the `grep` part shows up in the output.. but if you run the same command from the bash script, it doesn't...

Comment: @Dendory, there's no guaranteed relationship in terms of whether `grep` is or is not present in the output. I'd strongly suggest relying on documented promises, rather than observed behaviors.

Comment: Re: `echo $(ps -ax |grep httpd)`, that line's just always wrong. Use `echo "$(ps -ax |grep httpd)"`, with the quotes.

Comment: See my edit. This is not an issue of additional subprocesses in the shell script. The output is actually different. Try it with various grep options.

Comment: The assertion above is just plain factually wrong: The output from `grep` is **not** different, your `echo` is munging it together due to the lack of quoting, but the original output as `grep` emitted it before the shell munged it is exactly the same; you just don't *see* it, because you're capturing it via a command substitution and then string-splitting that command substitution into an argument list passed to `echo`.

Comment: Anyhow, you'd get the same bug from `echo $(ps ax | grep httpd)` at an interactive shell too (as long as your interactive interpreter is also bash and not, say, zsh)

Comment: Added the quotes. The difference is still the `ps` output

Comment: Only the `grep` difference is left, and as I said, there are no documented guarantees there either way, so there's no promise being broken, no reasonable contrary expectation, and no bug.

Comment: Well, and that's the question. What would be a proper way to count the number of processes running if `grep` may or may not be included?

Comment: Oh, that's an *easy* question. Don't use `ps | grep`, use `pgrep`, which is smart enough to ignore itself and its parents. BTW, you might edit to ask that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks right to me.  When you run `./a.sh`, two new processes will be created -- the new `bash` shell and the `bash` subshell created by the `$(...)`.  (Not the echo, like I wrote earlier.  Even using `/usr/bin/echo`, that would not get run until after the `ps`, so would not be counted.)

```
$ ps -ax -o pid,cmd | wc -l
267
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $( ps -ax -o pid,cmd | wc -l )
$ ./a.sh
269
```

Now to get rid of the extra subshell:

```
$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash
ps -ax -o pid,cmd | wc -l
[jack@marta ~]$ ./b.sh
268
```

Now, get rid of the extra process by not starting a new shell:

```
$ source b.sh
267
```

Comment: `echo` is a shell builtin, in-process for bash. The second one is the subshell for `$()`, not related to the `echo`.

Comment: Sure, but if you're writing an answer, please try to be accurate as to the details, or leave those details out.

Comment: Right -- there IS a /usr/bin/echo, but that's not being called here.  I'll fix the response.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edits -- this is an excellent answer as now written.